# How to resolve dependency problem preventing php8.1-common from being configured correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, php-8

I am trying to install php 8.1 on ubuntu 18.04 following steps provided here https://bobcares.com/blog/install-php-8-on-ubuntu-20-04/

However, I am getting this error :

```bash
dpkg: error processing package php8.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php8.1-common
 php8.1-readline
 php8.1-opcache
 php8.1-cli
 libapache2-mod-php8.1
 php8.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I have already tryed :

```
$ sudo apt install -f
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

but no success install :(

Comment: Since this is as much an OS configuration issue as a programming one, moving the question to https://askubuntu.com might get you an answer faster. It's probably worth adding some more details as well: rather than a link to the instructions you're following, show exactly what you've run so far, any previous versions of PHP you have installed, and so on.